# Migrating EJB2.1 Application

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, spring-data-jpa

I have a legacy financial application which is written using EJB2.1(Making use of Entity Beans, Stateless Session Beans and Couple of MDBs).
I want to migrate  the application to latest Java EE or Spring framework.  The application consists of around 400 entities and Entity beans are mainly used for Creating and Updating. 
For the viewing part a separate DAO layer is there and I don't want to touch that part.Also I want to keep the business logic written in service beans as it is very complex to re write.

i.e., I simply want to replace the ORM part of the system. The application is making use of JTA transactions.

Sorry to ask a very high level question, but which technology I can use to replace the ORM.

Spring/Hibernate
Java EE
The primary considerations for the application would be scalability, performance also ease of deployment.

I just want opinions on who have used these technologies, I don't want to start a war between 'evangelists'.

If you find the input is not suffcient please ask me I can provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the argument here is really between `EJB-3.x` versus `Spring/Hibernate` the first caveat being that one does not necessarily mutually exclude the other.  (annotations, container, testing, etc.)

there's lots of support in migrating to `EJB 2.1` to `EJB 3.x` and lots of toolsets to assist.  one of the principal challenges that i've seen with EJB is integration testing outside the container.  (for example. in a continuous integration environment)  There are `JTA` solutions, JNDI solutions and others to support but on the whole, i've found that there is more 'out-of-container' testing support on the Spring migration path than Java EE.  that said, there are foundation frameworks such as Arquillian from JBoss designed to support this.

so i would suggest you look at `EJB 2.1` to `EJB 3` migration paths and then look at the Arquillian framework for integration testing support

Comment: Thanks incomplete-co.de.